# Lindblad equation from microscopic principles for free particles with momentum interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, decoherence, open-quantum-systems

I'm rather familiar with the formalism of quantum master equations, but I'm struggling with deriving from microscopic principles the collapse operators for a particular case I need.

I consider two free particles, $A$ and $B$, with a total Hamiltonian $H=H_0+H_I$ composed by the individual kinetic terms $H_0=p_A^2/2m+p_B^2/2m$ and a weak nonlinear interaction term of the form $H_I = k(\vec{p}_A\cdot\vec{p}_B)^2$. [Note: this 'strange' term comes from a nonlinear dynamics I'm considering, but the form of this interaction is irrelevant. My question holds also for other types of interactions that involve some coupling between the momenta of the two particles.]

Following the standard derivation of a master equation from microscopic principles that can be found in several books or online resources, it is possible to write (after going into the interaction picture, Born-Markov approximation, ...) an equation of motion for the reduced state of $A$ that contains the term (see e.g. Eq.(3) [here](https://qutip.org/docs/4.0.2/guide/dynamics/dynamics-bloch-redfield.html))
$$
\text{Tr}_B\lbrace [\tilde{H}_I(t),[\tilde{H}_I(t-t^\prime),\tilde{\rho}_A(t)\rho_B(0)]]\rbrace \;.
$$
Here $\tilde{H}_I(t)=e^{iH_0 t} H_I e^{-iH_0 t}$, $\tilde{\rho}_A(t)= e^{iH_0 t} \tilde{\rho}_A e^{-iH_0 t}$, are $H_I$ and $\rho_A$ in the interaction picture.

Now, I'm struggling in calculating this term, and in obtaining an expression like the [Lindblad master equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian#Definition), in terms of collapse operators $\hat{A}_n$ acting with rate $h_{mn}$ (see link for notation). Typically, these are obtained from decomposing $H_I=\sum_i \hat{A}_i \otimes \hat{B}_i$, but I'm not sure I see such a clear decomposition in my case (see Eq.(31) [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/24/9/1258)). Also, I'm afraid the calculation is going to become very tedious unless some further approximation is made.

Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed? Or would you able to sketch some of the steps to follow? Is there some operator representation in which the calculations might be simpler (e.g. Fourier modes, bosonic operators, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get such a decomposition of $H_I$ by expanding the scalar product and then the square :\begin{align}
H_I &= k(\vec p_A\cdot\vec p_B)^2 \\
&= k \left(\sum_ip_{Ai} p_{Bi}\right)^2\\
&= k \sum_{ij} p_{Ai}p_{Aj} \otimes p_{Bi}p_{Bj}
\end{align}

Comment: This does solve what op is asking for, but for the derivation of the Lindblad equation this has to be decomposed even further into eigenoperators, which I assume can be done by writing everything in terms of the creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with this decomposition, and I was also thinking about it, but then? It is true that $H_i$ should be decomposed even further into eigenoperators of the 'bare' Hamiltonian $p_A^2/2m$, which is diagonal in momentum space...

Comment: After you decompose it into eigenoperators then everything else follows from the standard derivations, with some details like the spectral density or what approximations depending on you specific problem I guess